# jQuery change event code not running possible event conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

Let me start off by saying that this is my second day learning jQuery so I'm very much a beginner.

I've written a document ready function and all components are working except the countryField.change function I wrote. I'm pretty sure the web application already has a change function for this field and I'm not sure if there can be two of the same event on a field. When I say it's not working, I set a breakpoint in the Chrome debugger and it never enters the function.

Maybe I have to temporarily pause the existing event, run my code, then re-enable the default event?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var submitReady = true;
    var phoneField = $("p.phone").find("input");
    var phoneExt = $("p.Ext").find("input");
    var countryField = $("p.country").find("input");
    var stateField = $("p.state").find("input");
    var provinceField = $("p.Province").find("input");

    var regex = /^\([2-9][0-9]{2}\)\s+[2-9][0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{4}$/;

    phoneField.mask('(000) 000-0000', {placeholder: "(###) ###-####"});
    phoneExt.mask('00000', {placeholder: "#####"});

    $('#pardot-form').submit(function() {
        // DO STUFF
        if (submitReady) {
            if (phoneExt.val() != "") {
                phoneField.val(phoneField.val() + ' x' + phoneExt.val());
                return true;
            }
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    });
    phoneField.focusout(function() {
        if (regex.test($(this).val())) {
            submitReady = true;
            return true;
        }
        else {
            $(".form-field.phone").after( "<p class='tempError error no-label'>Please Enter a valid phone number: (###) ###-####</p>");
            submitReady = false;
        }
    });
    phoneField.focus(function() {
        $(".tempError").remove();
    });

    countryField.change(function() {
         phoneField.val("");
         provinceField.val("");
         stateField.val("");
         submitReady = true;
    });
});
```

Comment: You can have multiple event handlers on an element. They'll be executed in the order that they were defined. The only issue would if one of them submits the form, that would reload the page and stop any later handlers from running.

Comment: Thanks, neither results in submit so I should be able to define my event? So now I have to somehow figure out why it's not firing.

Comment: Make sure the selector is matching something. What is countryField.length?

Comment: Could you show us your HTML

Comment: Are the country inputs added dynamically?

Comment: maybe do a `$( "p.country" ).change(function() {...`

Comment: Yes, all of the inputs are added dynamically. If I get the value for countryField.length with a breakpoint just after it's defined, the length is 0 since the field starts off blank. If I let the page load and repeat it's undefined.

Comment: Not sure if showing the HTML would help as Barmar guessed, it's dynamically loaded:    <div id="contentForm">
%%content%%
<br style="clear:both"/>
</div>

Comment: @CesarBielich - Your solution worked! Not sure why, but it did. Thanks!

Comment: @RobG No problem, Ill make it an answer

Comment: @CesarBielich Thanks, that's saving me from looking up further on how to answer my own question and give someone credit ;D

Comment: If the whole form is dynamically loaded then NONE of the event bindings should work. Dynamic loading means you're using Javascript to create the form, it doesn't mean it's created dynamically on the server with a template.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, didn't know that. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Are you sure the country is an `<input>` field? Many forms use a drop-down menu of countries, so it should be `.find("select")`.

Comment: @Barmar Yes I noticed that as well yesterday, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
$( "p.country" ).change(function() {
    phoneField.val("");
    provinceField.val("");
    stateField.val("");
    submitReady = true;
});
```